# How to replace new line in a text input in Power Apps with "\n"?

Tags: powerapps

How to replace new line in a text input in Power Apps with "\n" so that I can send the user input as a JSON value?

I tried all and finally ended up with following solution :)

`Set( var_reformatted_prompt ,Concat(Split(TextInputPrompt.Text,""), If(IsMatch(Value,"\n"),"\n",Value))  )`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Substitute function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-replace-substitute) to search for new lines and the [Char function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-char) to create the character that represents the new line. Notice that some systems use `\r\n` as new lines, so it may be worth addressing both in a single expression:

```
With(
  {
    text: "Hello
world",
    lf: Char(10),
    crlf: Char(13) & Char(10)
  },
  Substitute(
    Substitute(text, crlf, "\n"),
    lf, "\n"))
```